# Sendmail relay authentication

Tags: sendmail, smtp

I'm trying to set up my sendmail to authenticate against a relay (comcast). I'm not seeing any attempts to authenticate at all. I'm trying to just debug how authentication works, and can't connect all the pieces...

I have, in my .mc file:

```
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`SMART_HOST', `relay:smtp.comcast.net.')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash /etc/mail/client-info')dnl
```

And in my /etc/mail/client-info:

```
AuthInfo:*.comcast.net "U:root" "I:comcast_user" "P:comcast_password"
```

Now, I know everything is fine with the u/p, as I could authenticate directly through SMTP, using telnet.

There are two things I don't understand.

1. When AuthInfo records are searched for, they are matched by the target hostname. How? Does it it use the map key (something I would expect), or uses the so-called "Domain" ("R:" parameter that I don't set in my auth-info line)
2. What is "U:", really? Sendmail README (http://www.sendmail.org/m4/smtp_auth.html) says it's "user(authoraztion id)", and "I:" is "authentication ID". That suggests that my username should be in "U:", actually, but http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/auth.html says that "I:" is your remote user name.

The session looks like this:

```
[root@manticore]/etc/mail# sendmail -qf -v
Warning: Option: AuthMechanisms requires SASL support (-DSASL)

Running /var/spool/mqueue/p97CgcWq023273 (sequence 1 of 399)
my@email.com... Connecting to smtp.comcast.net. port 587 via relay...
220 omta19.westchester.pa.mail.comcast.net comcast ESMTP server ready
>>> EHLO my.host.name
250-omta19.westchester.pa.mail.comcast.net hello [my.ip.add.res], pleased to meet you
250-HELP
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-SIZE 15728640
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250 OK
>>> STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>>> EHLO my.host.name
250-omta19.westchester.pa.mail.comcast.net hello [my.ip.add.res], pleased to meet you
250-HELP
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-SIZE 15728640
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 OK
>>> MAIL From:<> SIZE=2183
550 5.1.0 Authentication required
MAILER-DAEMON... aliased to postmaster
postmaster... aliased to root
root... aliased to my@email.com
postmaster... aliased to root
root... aliased to my@email.com
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 OK


[root@manticore]/etc/mail# sendmail -d0.1
Version 8.14.3
 Compiled with: DNSMAP LOG MAP_REGEX MATCHGECOS MILTER MIME7TO8 MIME8TO7
                NAMED_BIND NETINET NETINET6 NETUNIX NEWDB NIS PIPELINING SCANF
                SOCKETMAP STARTTLS TCPWRAPPERS USERDB XDEBUG
```

Thanks,
  Pawel.

Answer (score 1):

> if FEATURE(`authinfo') is used, then the hostname in the map entry
>   must match exactly the hostname of the ISP mailserver

See at your SMART_HOST + client-info

> What is "U:", really?

Well, [SMTP Authentication](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/smtp_auth.html) states in pure English

> U user (**authorization**) id
>
> I **authentication** id
>
> ...
>
> User **or** authentication id must exist as well as the password. All
>   other entries have default values. **If one** of user or authentication id
>   is **missing**, the **existing value is used** for the missing item.

Comment: In my .cf file, it says: `DSsmtp.comcast.net`, and in my client-info, it says `AuthInfo:smtp.comcast.net "U:*" "I:username" "P:password"`
All of this is literally (except for credentials). I don't see even an attempt to authenticate.

Comment: makemap hash client-info < client-info - yes? /etc/init.d/sendmail restart - yes? And just for test, in client-info "P:username"

Comment: Option: AuthMechanisms requires SASL support (-DSASL)

Comment: I have Makefiles that build my hashmaps. And I don't restart sendmail, as I was running it from command line as with `-q -v` flags.

Comment: yes, the -DSASL was the problem. saw your comment after posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was very simple. Default OpenBSD sendmail doesn't have SASL flag set, and can not do any authentication, even plain text. I actually expected that SASL is only used for "advanced" authentication. My -d0.1 output clearly shows no SASL flag.

For those who have the same issue: this page (http://theory14.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/openbsd-smtp-authtls-imaps-proxy/) vaguely (it's not a step-by-step how-to-fix-OpenBSD-sendmail-for-SASL page) explains on the necessary steps to go through. Basically, -- download userland source, and rebuild sendmail with -DSASL flag.

P.S. I think, the "U:" is really the user that runs sendmail, where "I:" is the user to authenticate to the client.